# How to show child dialog inside Tab control?

Tags: c++, winapi

WM_INITDIALOG and WM_NOTIFY code sections.

```
HWND hTabCtrl = nullptr;
HWND hCurrentTab = nullptr;
HWND hTab1 = nullptr;

LRESULT CALLBACK WINPROC(HWND hWnd,UINT uMsg,WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam)
{   


    hTabCtrl = GetDlgItem(hWnd, IDC_TAB1);

    g_hWnd = hWnd;
    ShowWindow(hTab1, SW_SHOW);
    switch(uMsg)
    {
        case WM_INITDIALOG:
            {
                //hInstance = 0; // Useless? 
                INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX ix;
                ix.dwSize = sizeof(INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX);
                ix.dwICC = ICC_TAB_CLASSES|ICC_UPDOWN_CLASS;
                InitCommonControlsEx(&ix);

                //ShowWindow(hTabCtrl, SW_SHOW);
                TCITEM ti;
                memset(&ti, 0, sizeof(ti));
                ti.mask = TCIF_TEXT; 
                ti.pszText = L"Basic Options";
                ti.cchTextMax = 255;
                TabCtrl_InsertItem(hTabCtrl,0,&ti); // 

                ti.pszText = L"Antis";
                TabCtrl_InsertItem(hTabCtrl,1,&ti);

                TabCtrl_SetCurSel(hTabCtrl,0);
                hTab1 = CreateDialog(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DLG2), /*handle of the tab control*/ hTabCtrl, (DLGPROC)GeneralDlgPrc);

                break;
            }

        // Macro so you don't need the crazy styled cast.
        case WM_NOTIFY: 
            {
                switch( ( ( LPNMHDR ) lParam) -> code ) 
                {
                case TCN_SELCHANGE: 
                    {
                        if( TabCtrl_GetCurSel( ( ( LPNMHDR ) lParam) -> hwndFrom ) == 0 ) 
                        {
                            ShowWindow( hTab1, SW_SHOW );

                        } 
                        else 
                        {

                        }

                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

I tried it like that and It doesn't show up. It overlays one of the tab borders, so it should exist, but it's not visible on the form control.

Here's the screenshot: http://puu.sh/1yt1b

EDIT: It works, but the position is wrong, should I manually set the position?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add Controls To Specific Tab Page in TabControl in C++ Win32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34164272/add-controls-to-specific-tab-page-in-tabcontrol-in-c-win32)

Comment: See this answer which provides an exhaustive example of using a dialog box within a tab control. https://stackoverflow.com/a/53108864/1466970

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to use SetWindowPos() to set the current position of my modeless dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `SetWindowPos`, which will make you pay a runtime cost, you should define the initial x/y offset of controls within your resource file. The resource editor you are using should allow this.